# Decorator args and kwargs returned within tuple

Tags: python, methods, arguments, decorator

I have the following decorator and class.

```
def auth(fn):

    def check_headers(self):
        print 'checking headers...'
        #self.headers work done here
        
    def inner(self, *args, **kwargs):
        check_headers(self)
        fn(self, args, kwargs)

    return inner

class Worker(object):

    @auth
    def work(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'auth passed'
        print args
        print kwargs


worker_obj = Worker()
worker_obj.work('arg', kw='kwarg')
```

Which outputs :

```
> checking headers...
> auth passed
> (('arg',), {'kw': 'kwarg'})
> {}
```

But am I expecting this :

```
> checking headers...
> auth passed
> ('arg',)
> {'kw': 'kwarg'}
```

How come the args/kwargs are getting put in a tuple when the original method (work()) is being run, post-decoration?

I know that stripping it down to

```
def auth(fn):
    return fn
```

returns the parameters correctly, but I need to do some work on the worker instance (self) before returning. I surely missed something about decorators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `fn(self, args, kwargs)`, you are passing two positional arguments: the tuple of `args`, and the dict of `kwargs`.  So if you call `work(1, x=2)`, you will call `func(self, (1,), {'x': 2})`.  To expand the origianl args and kwargs into separate arguments, you need to do

```
fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

This will mean that when you call `work(1, x=2)`, then you will also call `fn(self, 1, x=2)`.

You can see documentation on this [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Comment: Awesome, that was fast! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Because you put `kwargs` instead of `**kwargs`.

```
def inner(self, *args, **kwargs):
    check_headers(self)
    fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
```